# iOS 13 not recognizing contacts with country code

Tags: iphone, contacts, ios

This morning I downloaded brand new iOS 13 (Official Release) and found it very cool, specially dark mode.

The thing is that I started receiving calls and the contact names are not being identified, Ive found out that this is happening cause some contacts are registered with country code, for example:

[image]

In above image my friend Antonio is registered with country code: +52 1 (55) etc...

Before iOS 13 the number was formatted with parenthesis but now it doesn't.

And before iOS 13 the call identifier perfectly recognizes all numbers with that format, but now it doesn't either:

[image]

Coincidentally this exact thing happened to Antonio on his own iPhone so I suppose maybe its a very common issue.

Am I missing some new configuration or what can we do? Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about the caller's name appearing when they call or is it about how the phone number is formatted?  The question title asks one thing but the content mentions something else.

Comment: Also note that iOS 13.0 will be updated to 13.1 in about a week. You may have discovered one of the many bugs in iOS 13.0 that won't be fixed till 13.1 or later...

Comment: @SteveChambers precisely the reason for not jumping onto new versions before some reviews/feedbacks etc.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Check the country/region of your iPhone. Make sure it matches up with those numbers. Otherwise it wont detect them.

Comment: I’m having a similar issue with Australian phone numbers in iOS 13.4.1, that didn’t occur previously (prior to iOS 13 possibly). My language and region settings are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would engage Apple support using the iOS support app. They would be able to confirm this is a bug or possible document the setting no one has discovered yet to remedy this.

Comment: Anyone can edit this once we know for sure a bug number or workaround or which release fixes this. For now, it quacks like a duck to me.

Answer (score 0):

Download this app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/10-d%C3%ADgitos/id1476001299

This fixes the issue

> [image]

Comment: Hi can you explain what this app does? It would help save this post being deleted as spam. Also, did you develop this? [answer]

Comment: This app is not available in Australian App Store. Not sure what it actually does. Perhaps it scans your address book and updates phone numbers, converting to a specific format?